# Migrate Restify (throttler plugin) to Nest (throttle module)

Tags: nestjs, throttling, restify

I'm migrating my Restify project to Nest and I have to migrate the throttle plugin too. I noticed that the [Restify throttle plugin](http://restify.com/docs/plugins-api/#throttle) uses `burst` (in requests) and `rate` (in seconds) as options for throttling.

Are these two properties equivalent to [Nest throttle module](https://github.com/nestjs/throttler#throttlermodule) properties `limit` (in requests) and `ttl` (in seconds)?

It makes most sense to me if they would be the same but I can't find much information about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a cursory look at their documentation, yes